# Should this edit to an answer be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16083284/593627
with it's edit history here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16083284/edit/6e724005-9755-433a-b591-1eda53e46bbe

To me it appears the question poster has asked a question, seen the posted answer and edited to be what he believes is correct (changing the meaning of the answer posted).

Should this revision be rolled back, or maybe not because he indicated what he did in a comment?

Comment: To me this looks like a "meh" answer was turned into an "awesome" answer...though, it would have been better off as answer on it's own, given how much the answer was changed.

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of what I'm thinking, he definitely made it better but my point is that he changed the meaning. I'd have thought a self-answer would've been better in this case too, but given it's been done I guess you're saying to just leave it as it is now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually happened to me on Arqade the other day: I [answered a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-can-i-tell-what-glowy-ring-buffs-the-enemy-team-currently-has/113887#113887), and the asker [edited it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/113887/revisions), giving it a complete makeover (as well as adding new information to it that wasn't originally there). I rolled back the edit based on [my comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-can-i-tell-what-glowy-ring-buffs-the-enemy-team-currently-has/113887#comment152950_113887) which I left for the asker. I'll reproduce the comment here as I think it sums it up here quite nicely as well:

> While formatting improvements are generally OK, it's not appropriate to completely replace somebody else's answer with your own writing and formatting. Plus, I do not feel comfortable taking credit for something I didn't write. If you want to post your own answer, please do so.

In your case, the asker has even modified the answerer's last statement as opposed to removing it altogether for being editorial noise, changing this:

> Anyway, sorry I can't be more helpful than that or give you a definite answer! Anyway, hope it helps!

To this:

> Anyway, sorry I couldn't give an answer to the exact question asked - *hiding implementation of a generic class in a nested generic class to give easier signature for method calls*. Even if any name existed, it has to be very specific to the language (or similar languages) since generics/type inference etc are involved. Anyway, hope it helps!

I'd say that's going as far as *putting his words in the answerer's mouth* IMO, as opposed to just harmlessly removing the statement, because it's a personal statement from the answerer as opposed to a factual statement. I wouldn't have been comfortable with that myself, which is why I rolled back the edit on my answer on Arqade.

With all this in mind however, as the answer belongs to its author, and the edit doesn't appear ill-intentioned in any way, I'd say it's best to leave the edit alone. It's certainly a good idea nevertheless, to post a comment notifying the editor (with the @name syntax) that such radical edits are inappropriate.

Comment: Is it up to the original poster of the answer to make that call (particularly as the editor suggested changing it if there was a problem as is the case with my example), or should I roll it back myself?

Comment: @George Duckett: I think we'll let the answerer decide. I'll post a comment there to notify the asker who edited it.